# Function to expand a parent node dynamically from json in a dhtmlx tree

Tags: javascript, json, tree, dhtmlx, dynamic-loading

On the dhtmlx documentation, I see this:

> The following method is responsible for specifying the way server side URL is constructed during dynamical loading calls:

```
<script>
    tree.setXMLAutoLoadingBehaviour(mode);
</script>
```

> The following modes variants are available here:
>
> function - is used for calling user-defined handler that should be set as the first parameter of setXMLAutoLoading() method.

So I understand that I need to write a function to add one layer of children to the actual node (the selected node), if it has children. But what I don't understand, is how I should do this, as I have some difficulty finding the right parameters to use, to be able to find the children and add them to the tree.

I am loading a local json file, with `.loadJSON("data.json");`. Right now, I know I should change the behavior to function and call a function that will load the children of the clicked/expended node. I've named that function `loadBranch` in the code below.

```
myTree.setXMLAutoLoadingBehaviour("function");
myTree.setXMLAutoLoading(function (id) { loadBranch(id)});
```

But I am not able to write a function that will only find and add those children into my `dhtmlx tree`. Could any of you give me a code snippet that could be used as this function?

Thanks anyway.

PS: My "ultimate" goal is to create a default dhtmlx tree that can load a json dynamically, to compare it's performance with other trees.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
mytree.setXMLAutoLoadingBehaviour("function");
mytree.setXMLAutoLoading (function(id){
    // here based on ID you need to load some XML
    mytree.loadXML(myFunction(id));
});
```

Comment: Yes, but do you have an idea of the `function`? It is the part that I find difficult to do, as my tree does not have a special way to name it's IDs, they are simply unique.

Comment: Function will receive clicked node id:
`mytree.setXMLAutoLoadingBehaviour("function");
mytree.setXMLAutoLoading(function(id){alert(id);});`. For more you may want to check dhtmlxForum at [here](http://forum.dhtmlx.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=37417) or [here](http://forum.dhtmlx.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=141)